# Modify a line of a txt file - Java

Tags: java, netbeans, io

In my text file I have customer details, such as company name, company address, etc. My file's content is in italian so ragione sociale is company name, indirizzo is address, etc.

Text file contents:

```
ID:1
ragione sociale:Telecom Italia S.p.A.
indirizzo:Via Gaetano Negri, n. 1
comune:Milano
cap:20123
provincia:MI
nazione:italia
partita iva:00488410010
codice fiscale:00488410010
telefono:119
---------------------------------
ID:2
ragione sociale:Wind Tre Spa
indirizzo:Casella Postale 14155
comune:Milano
cap:20152
provincia:MI
nazione:Italia
partita iva:13378520152
codice fiscale:13378520152
telefono:155
---------------------------------
```

When a user edits for example `ID:2's` detail I want to print the edited information in the same text file and obtain this:

```
ID:1
ragione sociale:Telecom Italia S.p.A.
indirizzo:Via Gaetano Negri, n. 1
comune:Milano
cap:20123
provincia:MI
nazione:italia
partita iva:00488410010
codice fiscale:00488410010
telefono:119
---------------------------------
ID:2
ragione sociale: new Company name
indirizzo: new address
comune:Milano
cap:20152
provincia:MI
nazione:Italia
partita iva:13378520152
codice fiscale:13378520152
telefono:155
---------------------------------
```

Using my code at the bottom of this question, the new text file is:

```
ID:1
ragione
sociale:Telecom
Italia
S.p.A.
indirizzo:Via
Gaetano
Negri,
n.
1
comune:Milano
cap:20123
provincia:MI
nazione:italia
partita
iva:00488410010
codice
fiscale:00488410010
telefono:119
---------------------------------
ID:2
ragione sociale:company name
sociale:Wind
Tre
Spa
indirizzo:Casella
Postale
14155
comune:Milano
cap:20152
provincia:MI
nazione:Italia
partita
iva:13378520152
codice
fiscale:13378520152
telefono:155
---------------------------------
```

But when I put my text file into an `ArrayList` it considers each space as a new element in the list for example company name:

```
list[0] company
list[1] name
```

But I want:

```
list[0] company name
```

Can someone help me?

My Java code:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("customers.txt"));
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (s.hasNext()) list.add(s.next());
s.close();

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i).equals("ID:2")) {
        //list.remove(i+1);
        list.set(i+1, "ragione sociale:company name");
        break;
    }  
}

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i)); 
}

FileWriter w=new FileWriter("output.txt");
BufferedWriter b=new BufferedWriter(w);
PrintWriter printer= new PrintWriter(b);

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    printer.println(list.get(i));
}
printer.close();
```

Comment: You should research `Scanner#next()` vs `Scanner#nextLine()`.

Comment: `Scanner#next()` uses any whitespace characters (` `, `\n`, `\r\n`) as the delimiter, you need to use `Scanner#nextLine()` and parse that line in whichever way suits you. For example: `String companyName = scanner.nextLine().split(":")[1];`.